# SetState Is Not A Function on OnChange

Tags: javascript, reactjs, state, onchange, setstate

Working to get a slider to change the value of "text" in the React state.

Keep getting an error:

"App.js:90 Uncaught TypeError: this.setState is not a function" despite my best troubleshooting efforts.

What could the fix be?

```
  class App extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
      super(props);
      this.state = {list: [{x: "Before Pool", y:85000}, {x: "After Pool", y:82000}], text: 0, options: {bathrooms:'', bedrooms:'', sqft:''}};
    }

  componentDidMount() {
        setTimeout(() => {
         this.setState({list: [{x: "Before Pool", y:60000}, {x: "After Pool", y:30000}]});
         console.log("testing", this.state.text);
       }, 2000) ;
  }
  handleChange (event) {
    console.log("from handle change", event);
   this.setState({text : event });
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <div className="App">
          <div>
             <div style={wrapperStyle}>
               <p># of Bathrooms</p>
               <Slider min={0} max={20} defaultValue={3} onChange={this.handleChange} />
             </div>
```

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you need to bind the `handleChange` method

```
<Slider min={0} max={20} defaultValue={3} onChange={this.handleChange.bind(this)}
```

Comment: can you mark my answer as right answer, so that others can get help form it

Answer (score 1):

You need to bind your state to the callback within `setTimeout` since you are in a different context.
I belive this would do the trick:

```
setTimeout(() => {
 this.setState({list: [{x: "Before Pool", y:60000}, {x: "After Pool", y:30000}]});
 console.log("testing", this.state.text);
   }.bind(this), 2000) ;
```

Comment: Glad to hear it, if your issue is fully solved it helps SO out for you to accept an answer to indicate that to other users. Of course, it doesn't need to be mine, but it would be helpful if you accepted one.

Answer (score 1):

The answer is pretty simple: You're looking at the wrong `this`.

Since you're writing a callback in a closure it's important to know that you can't access the `this` from outside. It always refers to the current context.

As a workaround, define your own variable (typically called `self`) to use inside the closure:

```typescript
componentDidMount() {
    var self = this; // copy the reference
    setTimeout(() => {
        self.setState({list: [{x: "Before Pool", y:60000}, {x: "After Pool", y:30000}]});
        console.log("testing", this.state.text);
    }, 2000) ;
}
```

Comment: Appreciate it @Mario! Your answer echoes the other two answers - great analysis.

Answer (score 1):

You need to bind the  `handleChange`method here

```
<Slider min={0} max={20} defaultValue={3} onChange={this.handleChange} />
```

This should look like this

```
<Slider min={0} max={20} defaultValue={3} onChange={this.handleChange.bind(this)} />
```

Or you can simply use Arrow Functions in the signature of the method, is better to use this all the time to save you to bind all the time. It should look like this:

```
handleChange = event => {
    console.log("from handle change", event);
    this.setState({text : event });
  }
```